# Installshield 2013 Professional/Premier

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, installshield, filesize

Our IT department wants to take advantage of deploying msi packages/imgs through **Landesk Management Suite**. We have been deploying images on workstations using usb **Smartdeploy**. I've been asked to find an msi packaging tool that can handle packaged programs with large file size.

Is **Installshield 2013 Professional/Premier**  able to build an MSI package out of package installers with huge file size (i.e. Microsoft Office 2010/Autocad Package)? And if so, what's the limit of (number of programs/file size) you can fit in the msi package?

Replies and Suggestions are all welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authoring large windows installer packages (.MSI) is a nuanced discussion.  Strictly speaking an MSI can be up to 2GB.  However I personally never build an MSI larger then about 200MB.   The 2GB is a hard limit and the 200MB is a judgement call dealing with UAC / DEP scanning activities that windows does that will really slow an installer down.

You get around these limits by building MSI's with external .CAB files instead of embedded CABs.   This way the MSI is small for initial scanning.

Another limit to MSI is 32K files.  Once you go past that it gets trickier but possible.  The real problem though becomes a scalability problem.  Really large installers tend to become harder to maintain (upgrade strategy, testing)  take a very long time to build and a large amount of time to install  ( one of Windows Installer strengths is also it's weakness as all the infrastructure to know what's being installed and manage it really takes a toll on installation performance ).

If you are using setup.exe to launch your installers, Windows also has a hard limit on the size of an EXE. The total size of the EXE with streamed data must be less than 4GB or it will not launch. While an MSI's 2GB limit makes this seem far off, adding multiple large PRQs to the installer can rapidly exceed the 4GB limit. You can also get around this limit by building the setup.exe with external PRQ files.

Comment: Thanks for the info Christopher. External CAB files it is!

Comment: Thanks for the additional Setup.EXE comments, Michael.  Personally I can't imagine redistributing a self extracting EXE that big but I suppose someone does.  By that size I'm thinking a DVD build and distributing an ISO.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the additional info